# FPDF - File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

**Controller:**

```
public function mensualAction() {
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tokens.pdf"');

        require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
        $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hola Mundo!');
        $pdf->Output();
    }
```

Not see the File PDF

[image]

What I want is to write text in a PDF

Docu Oficial site FPDF

[image]

Comment: I may not get the question, but PDF is NOT plain text; has never been and will never be.

Comment: @MaxWyss I want to type something in a PDF, plain text theme is the error it gives me the PDF file viewer

Comment: Does the tool you are using the generation of Annotations? If so, you might have fewer problems by adding a Text annotation (aka comment).

Comment: @MaxWyss I want to create a PDF from consultations with MYSQL Model

Comment: Note to self: check what you have written before hitting the Add Comment button… my sentence should have read "Does the tool you are using _support_ the generation of Annotations?